# Sequelize check row exists, and return boolean

Tags: promise, sequelize.js

I am attempting to use Sequelize to query an association table to see if one user is following another. If the relationship exists, I want to return true. If not, return false. I want to return this response to the "following" section of toProfileJSONFor (see below).

Based on logging, everything seems to be working as expected, except I receive a promise back instead of my boolean value. I've read up as much as I can find on promises, but still can't seem to figure out my issue.

Here is the result that I am currently receiving:

```
{
    "profile": {
        "username": "superman1",
        "bio": null,
        "image": "",
        "following": {
            "isFulfilled": false,
            "isRejected": false
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that this is a problem with promises, but I cannot figure out a resolution.

```js
User.prototype.toProfileJSONFor = function(user){
  return {
    username: this.username,
    bio: this.bio,
    image: this.image || 'genericImage.jpg',
    following: user.isFollowing(this.id) //this is where I am having issues
  };

User.prototype.isFollowing = function(id){
  let userId = this.id; // current userId
  let followId = id; //profile Id


  return FollowerFolloweds.findAll({
    where: { followedId: followId, followerId: userId},raw : true })
    .then(function(result) {
      if(result.length !=0){
        return true;
      }  {
        return false;
      }

    })
}
```

The expected result would be:

```
{
    "profile": {
        "username": "superman1",
        "bio": null,
        "image": "",
        "following": true 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
User.prototype.toProfileJSONFor = function(user){
  return user.isFollowing(this.id)
    .then((following) => {
        username: this.username,
        bio: this.bio,
        image: this.image || 'genericImage.jpg',
        following
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks so much for your comment. Unfortunately, this returned the following      {
    "profile": {
        "isFulfilled": false,
        "isRejected": false
    }
}